# Binomial distribution, hypotheses testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, binomial-distribution

Suppose the following instance of the hypotheses testing:
suppose that the true state of the coin is that it is either exactly fair, or that it shows heads with probability $0.51$, and there are no other possibilities. Then a test statistic would be $T=X/10$, the proportion of heads out of $10$ tosses. What would be a suitable rejection region for $T$?

Well, clearly if $T≤0.5$, we can't reject $H_{10}$.

My question is:why literally we can't reject $H_{10}$ and **what type I and II errors do we commit
by rejecting it**?

Comment: If you have $\leq$ 50% heads then the data are more consistent with the null; you'd hardly want to reject in favor of the alternative when it's less consistent with T. If you specify a rejection region R, you can compute $P(T\in R|p=0.5)$ and $P(T\not\in R|p=0.51)$  quite readily, (it's a straight binomial cdf calculation both times), and so get the two error rates. Is your question really just "how do I calculate tail probabilities with a binomial distribution?" or does it boil down to "what is the definition of type I and type II error?". I'm unclear what the specific difficulty is.

Comment: My actual question was whether we can with certainity deny $H_{10}$ or rather what type I and II do we commit by rejecting $H_{10}$? Some calculation of these two errors would help.The definition of them is clear: $\alpha$ is the probability of rejecting $H_{10}$ if $H_{10}$ is true, right?

Comment: Ah, then it seems like part of the difficulty is indeed to do with "what is the definition of type I and type II error"  -- you cannot commit a type II error by rejecting the null; the definition of type II error is about failing to reject the null (when it's false)

Comment: And what about type I? What error of type I do we commit if we reject $H_{10}$ when $T\leq 0.5$ ?